# Number Of email accounts can be hosted on server using cpanel

Tags: linux, email, cpanel, hosting-services

I need to know how many number of accounts be hosted on a dedicated server with `cpanel`, with a HDD of 100 GB , and also max number of accounts, And also I would need assistance on "How I use a single same domain for multiple email servers "

Comment: Check with the host you bought the cPanel Interface from.  The limit is not imposed by cPanel, it's imposed by the host.

Comment: Thank you eyoung , What if I bought a server and a cpanel licence , or please tell me in general how many maximum accounts can be hosted on a basic dedicated server !

Comment: Using Raja's formula from his answer, you could work to determine the maximum disk size you need, ie `MaxQuota * NumberOfUsers = HardDriveSize`

Comment: AFAIK cPanel imposes no limitation on the number of accounts.  The server you buy and what it comes with is still up to the host you buy it from.  The adders that the host provides is how they make money.  As such the host dictates the number of mailboxes.  If you were your own host the number would be dictated by you with this formula, `HardDriveSize / NumberOfUsers = Quota` As for relaying mail across multiple domains, that is generally discouraged.

Comment: I rewrote the comment and it moved, I apologize.  Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: @eyoung100 I got it , for 100 Gb with 10 MB per account I get around 10240 email accounts , Am i right ???

Comment: Yes, but you need to check the Documentation for how cPanel counts a MB. Also note that at 10MB Quotas mailbox users will not be able to store big attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Reference : [Cpanel Documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Email+Accounts#EmailAccounts-ChangeQuota)

Hello ,

As per the official documentation , How many number of accounts is proportional to how much quota for each email account.

E-mail server got restrictions on User's E-mail account storage restrictions.
If Operating system is 32-bit , then allowed max quota is 2GB and if it is 64 -bit then it is 4 GB.

Indeed you can change this setting too from Change Quota.

for more information have a look on above reference link.

---

Regards

Genupula